# Swift Error Displaying NSAttributedString with Non-Breaking Spaces and Multiple Lines

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, line-breaks, spaces

Apologies if this is obvious but I've been searching for a while and this one's stumping me.

I have an NSAttributedString which contains:

1) A "fill-in-the-blank"-esque substring comprised of non-breaking spaces with an underline style applied to that substring (e.g. "\u{00a0}\u{00a0}\u{00a0}" with an underline style applied to only that substring; I was originally using underscores but the space between them was problematic since my text has opacity so you could see either the space between or the overlap)

2) multiple line breaks at the end of the string with choices to fill in the blank (e.g. "...\na) first choice\nb) second choice\nc) last choice")

I'm then displaying this NSAttributedString in a label with numberOfLines set to 0.

This works fine 90% of the time, except for the 10% of the time when the non-breaking "fill-in-the-blank" appears within wrapping distance of the end of a line, meaning that it's pushed to the next line (as expected), which pushes all of the other text forward, and if enough pushing occurs throughout the paragraph, it pushes the final "choice" line (e.g. "\nc) last choice") out of the label completely so it doesn't display the final line of the string!? In other words, my label SEEMS to calculate how big it needs to be before the non-breaking spaces are applied, so if additional lines are then created by the non-breaking spaces/substrings, the final line is chopped off and not displayed at all.

Is there some other way to create or attribute this non-breaking "fill-in-the-blank" so that it won't character-wrap (i.e. keep it all on the same line) but my label will understand/re-calculate that additional lines have been created by said non-wrapping? As I mentioned, my label already has numberOfLines set to 0; perhaps there's some sort of paragraph style or other label setting I haven't been able to locate? Or it's just a Swift bug but someone out there knows a work-around?

Below are some snippets from my code:

```
let underlineString = "\u{00a0}\u{00a0}\u{00a0}\u{00a0}\u{00a0}"
let myTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue): UIFont(name: "My Font", size: round(self.view.frame.width / 15)) as Any, NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.9)]

let myLabel = UILabel()
myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
myLabel.textAlignment = .center
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0

var myText = "What do you think about \u{00a0}\u{00a0}\u{00a0}\u{00a0}\u{00a0} and then what about this extra stuff at the end?\na) first choice\nb) second choice\nc) last choice"
var myAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:myText, attributes: myTextAttributes)
myAttributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleThick.rawValue, range: (myText as NSString).range(of:underlineString))
myLabel.attributedText = myAttributedText
self.view.addSubview(myLabel)

myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.height).isActive = true
myLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
myLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
myLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myLabel.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

After even more research, it's pretty clear that UILabel has a lot of bugs these days when it comes to attributed strings, so not sure if there's a technical work-around for the non-breaking space issue as described above.

With that said, I was able to work-around this particular bug by switching back to regular characters for my "fill-in-the-blank" substring, setting the foregroundColor for those characters to clear, and then setting the underlineColor to white so it wouldn't adopt the foregroundColor.